# How can I use my Github pages HTML for a Google Domain?

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I've recently purchased a domain name from Google Domains, and would like to use my existing GitHub Pages HTML on the new name. I've created a CNAME on my GitHub that references the new domain, and the GitHub address now reroutes to the other Domain successfully, but said domain has no content. I've tried to reference the GitHub Pages code on the Google Domain through a "CNAME" and "A" resource record, but none of these have worked successfully. I believe I need an "A" resource record on the Google Domain, but neither [GitHub's overview](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider) or [Google's](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251147) is clear on what information should be included where. Google's format includes 4 fields to be filled in: Name, Type, TTL, and IPv4. I assume "type" should be "A", TTL should be irrelevant, IPv4 should be the 2 values listed in GitHub's overview (`192.30.252.153` and `192.30.252.154`) and "Name" should be `[username].github.io`. When I tried to put these in, however, I continued to see DNS errors when trying to access my site. I've tried to follow [all relevant guides](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) to the best of my ability, but I seem to be making some fundamental mistake. While other questions ask this as well, they all have been resolved with the provision of [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) or [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/quick-start-setting-up-a-custom-domain/). I've spent, as of now, 5 hours trying to use these links to enable custom domains, but haven't been able to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I apologize if I did something wrong in the above post that warranted a downvote. If I did, please let me know what so I can fix it immediately :)

Comment: any update on this?